# Create a canvas that responds to both mouseclick(s) and touch

Tags: html, canvas, touch, mouselistener

I have a canvas that will respond to mouseclicks (or did until I changed the code) and am trying to implement a portion of the script that will respond to touch (ipad, smartphone, tablet, etc.).  However, I am stuck between the two; when I try one method, it breaks the other and vice versa.

Thoughts?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var canvas, ctx, canvasX, canvasY, mouseIsDown = 0;

    function init() {
        canvas = document.getElementById("can");
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDown, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseXY, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("touchstart", touchDown, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("touchmove", touchXY, true);
        canvas.addEventListener("touchend", touchUp, false);

        document.body.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseUp, false);
        document.body.addEventListener("touchcancel", touchUp, false);
    }

    function mouseUp() {
        mouseIsDown = 0;
        mouseXY();
    }

    function touchUp() {
        mouseIsDown = 0;
        // no touch to track, so just show state
        showPos();
    }

    function mouseDown() {
        mouseIsDown = 1;
        mouseXY();
    }

    function touchDown() {
        mouseIsDown = 1;
        touchXY();
    }

    function mouseXY(e) {
        if (!e)
            var e = event;
        canvasX = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
        canvasY = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
        showPos();
    }

    function touchXY(e) {
        if (!e)
            var e = event;
        e.preventDefault();
        canvasX = e.targetTouches[0].pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
        canvasY = e.targetTouches[0].pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
        showPos();
    }

function color(obj) {
    switch (obj.id) {
        case "green":
            x = "green";
            break;
        case "blue":
            x = "blue";
            break;
        case "red":
            x = "red";
            break;
        case "yellow":
            x = "yellow";
            break;
        case "orange":
            x = "orange";
            break;
        case "black":
            x = "black";
            break;
        case "white":
            x = "white";
            break;
    }
    if (x == "white") y = 14;
    else y = 2;

}

function draw() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(prevX, prevY);
    ctx.lineTo(currX, currY);
    ctx.strokeStyle = x;
    ctx.lineWidth = y;
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
}

function erase() {
    var m = confirm("Want to clear");
    if (m) {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
        document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.display = "none";
    }
}

function save() {
    document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.border = "2px solid";
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
    document.getElementById("canvasimg").src = dataURL;
    document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.display = "inline";
}

function findxy(res, e) {
    if (res == 'down') {
        prevX = currX;
        prevY = currY;
        currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
        currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;

        flag = true;
        dot_flag = true;
        if (dot_flag) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.fillStyle = x;
            ctx.fillRect(currX, currY, 2, 2);
            ctx.closePath();
            dot_flag = false;
        }
    }
    if (res == 'up' || res == "out") {
        flag = false;
    }
    if (res == 'move') {
        if (flag) {
            prevX = currX;
            prevY = currY;
            currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
            currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
            draw();
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't passing the event object to any of the handlers:

This:

```
function mouseUp() {
    mouseIsDown = 0;
    mouseXY();
}
```

should be:

```
function mouseUp(e) {  // <- e
    mouseIsDown = 0;
    mouseXY(e);        // e ->
}
```

(and similar for the others)

Also be careful using `pageX/Y` as these are [not part of any standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent/pageX):

> This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not
>   use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every
>   user. There may also be large incompatibilities between
>   implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

Better use `getBoundingClientRect()` combined with `clientX/Y`:

```
function mouseXY(e) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    canvasX = e.clientX - rect.left;
    canvasY = e.clientY - rect.top;
    showPos();
}
```

You can also consolidate `mouseXY()`/`touchXY()` by passing in the touch object from the touch handlers:

```
function touchDown(e) {
    mouseIsDown = 1;
    mouseXY(e.targetTouches[0]);
}
```